# Название функции редактирование полей в товаре аналогичной ,как для категории product_cat_edit_form_fields?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

хочу добавить в админке на страну товара дополнительный редактор текста нужен хук добавления полей в товар WooCommerce
аналогичный тому, что ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
такое поле добавить под первым внизу код который добавляет, но не знаю хука для страницы товара

```
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'bbloomer_wp_editor_add', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_wp_editor_add() {
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="seconddesc"><?php echo __( 'Second Description', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>

      <?php
      $settings = array(
         'textarea_name' => 'seconddesc',
         'quicktags' => array( 'buttons' => 'em,strong,link' ),
         'tinymce' => array(
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'bold,italic,strikethrough,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,blockquote,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,link,unlink,separator,undo,redo,separator',
            'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
         ),
         'editor_css' => '<style>#wp-excerpt-editor-container .wp-editor-area{height:175px; width:100%;}</style>',
      );

      wp_editor( '', 'seconddesc', $settings );
      ?>

        <p class="description"><?php echo __( 'This is the description that goes BELOW products on the category page', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: И в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: название хука какое для страницы товара, который делал бы тоже не для категории ,а для товара, что  и product_cat_edit_form_fields?

Comment: Сперва оформи вопрос нормально, что бы его можно было понять. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Почитай по ссылке выше. Особенно внимательно со слов "Пишите грамотно!"